# Looping over MAPE function in Pandas throwing error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 1,2], 'plat' : ['and','and','ios','ios'], 'd30_real' : [1.2,1.4,1.5,1.9], 'd3_d30':[1.1,1.5,1.5,1.8], 'd7_d30':[1.4,1.5,1.6,1.9], 'd14_d30':[1.2,1.3,1.5,2.0]})
```

I want to calculate the MAPE with Sklearn function comparing the column on the lista_target as real value and the columns of the lista_com as predictions. This last list has to be A LIST OF LISTS. This cannot be changed.

```
lista_target = ['d30_real']
lista_com = [['d3_d30','d7_d30','d14_d30']]
mape_hm = pd.DataFrame()
```

This is the loop to generate the MAPE results:

```
for i in range(len(lista_target)):
  for e in range(len(lista_com[i])):
    mape_hm[i][e] = df1.groupby(by = ['id','plat']).apply(lambda x: mean_absolute_percentage_error(x[lista_target[i]], x[lista_com[i][e]]))
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

I understand that this is because it is not finding the position '0' on the lista_target. I would like what I am doing wrong, as I need to read the string inside the list, no the position.

This would be the output (fake numbers):

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 1,2], 'plat' : ['and','and','ios','ios'], 'd30_real' : [1.2,1.4,1.5,1.9], 'MAPE_d3_d30':[0.02,0.03,0.4,0.0], 'MAPE_d7_d30':[0.03,0.04,0.06,0], 'MAPE_d14_d30':[0.0,0.02,0,0.09]})
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I've added the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: there is no [e] entrance for mape_hm[i], you can add right after the for i loop mape_hm[i] = pd.serias or [] to overcome KeyError

Comment: Are you sure of the provided values?

Comment: It's a sample. I didn't calculated the mapes manually. The percentage may not match.

Comment: You must make this clear then, one would expect the real values…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your question, that you use groupby on `['id','plat']` columns then I write the answer with `groupby` and use apply on it and create the dataframe for [`sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html) for columns that you want.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error

cols = [['d3_d30'], ['d7_d30', 'd14_d30']]
lst = []
def f_mape(x):
    dct = {}
    for col in cols:
        for c in col:
            dct[f'real_{c}'] = mean_absolute_percentage_error(x['d30_real'], x[c])
    lst.append(dct)

df1.groupby(['id', 'plat']).apply(lambda x: f_mape(x))
print(pd.DataFrame(lst))
```

Output:

```
   real_d3_d30  real_d7_d30  real_d14_d30
0     0.083333     0.166667      0.000000
1     0.000000     0.066667      0.000000
2     0.071429     0.071429      0.071429
3     0.052632     0.000000      0.052632
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks. The thing is that I need to maintain the list of lists for cols list. I cannot do it other way.

Comment: @MatmataHi, hi, welcome, I can't understand, can you give me an example...?

Comment: If you take a look at lista_com = [['d3_d30','d7_d30','d14_d30']], it is a list of lists. And it has to remain this way. I cannot use only a list, as you did. My issue is located here, when I need to itinerate the nested list.

Comment: @MatmataHi, edited answer, Do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compute the MAPE per column, per group:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error as mape
(df1
 .groupby(['id','plat'])[lista_com[0]]
 .transform(lambda g: mape(df1.loc[g.index, lista_target[0]], g))
 .add_prefix('MAPE_')
)
```

output:

```
   MAPE_d3_d30  MAPE_d7_d30  MAPE_d14_d30
0     0.083333     0.166667      0.000000
1     0.071429     0.071429      0.071429
2     0.000000     0.066667      0.000000
3     0.052632     0.000000      0.052632
```

full output:

```
out = df1.drop(columns=lista_com[0]).join(df1
 .groupby(['id','plat'])[lista_com[0]]
 .transform(lambda g: mape(df1.loc[g.index, lista_target[0]], g))
 .add_prefix('MAPE_')
)
```

output:

```
   id plat  d30_real  MAPE_d3_d30  MAPE_d7_d30  MAPE_d14_d30
0   1  and       1.2     0.083333     0.166667      0.000000
1   2  and       1.4     0.071429     0.071429      0.071429
2   1  ios       1.5     0.000000     0.066667      0.000000
3   2  ios       1.9     0.052632     0.000000      0.052632
```

Comment: have you given it a try?